# What are the ways to monitor Power BI service activity?

Tags: performance, powerbi

I am working on a report to monitor certain things on the Power BI report Server.  I was wondering what items others may be monitoring on reports and how do they do it.

Some examples of things I want to monitor:

A.  Whether the scheduled data refreshes failed or succeeded.

1. Would love to be able to get the failure message.

B.  What is the average response time of a query.

1. Is there a way to determine when the report is first opened.  I would like to calculate initial load time.

C.  What was the longest response time of a query per day.

D.  How many times a query took longer than 5 seconds.

Comment: If you have powerbi Premium then you can use:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-premium-monitor-capacity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-metrics-app